# How to force a refresh with header?

Tags: php, redirect, upload, cache-control, page-refresh

I have a web page that displays user uploaded images. The images are cached with a long max-age such that users do not need to retrieve them from the server every time they view the page. However, this creates a problem when a user starts to replace images (the file names are in serial numbers 01.jpg, 02.jpg, etc). The user would still see the old images after an upload unless he clicks the refresh button.

Is there a way (without appending query string to all images) to force a hard refresh upon redirection to this page after an upload? Currently, I am using the PHP header function to do the redirection:

```
header("Location: //$host/user/$id");
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your caching mechanism. If you want control over when the browser should cache-bust (without fingerprinting) you need to set it to `must-revalidate` (so basically no caching). This comes at a performance loss. You can get some semblance of caching using [ETags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) and `304 Not Modified` but the overhead of the request might already be too bad.

You can't make a request that busts the cache on some other resource, that's not how the web works.

---

I would recommend using fingerprinting. Is there a reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: I want to consider other easier options if there is any first because it would mean extra coding on the user page.

Comment: To the people who downvoted: can you please explain why you downvoted?

Comment: I dunno why the heavy downvotes on your answer. Up yours for trying to help. A better reason why I don't want fingerprinting is because it prevents caching and as rightly pointed out by you, ETags is less efficient. A hard refresh is still my preferred option.

Comment: The hard refresh is a client-side thing, you command the browser to not use any cache. There is no way to do this from the server. As for the downvotes, I guess there is just a lot of general misconceptions on how caching works.

Comment: I can use javascript if a hard reload is not possible using PHP. Can you include the above comment as part of your answer so that I can accept it, since this is the answer I am looking for? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you know of a way to do this with JavaScript I'd like to see it.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with JS by testing for the referrer condition and using `location.reload()` for the hard refresh.

Comment: Ok, but does that affect the images?

Comment: Yes, it does force the browser to fetch the images instead of using the cache.